# WatchOS 6 Socket Programming

Tags: ios, sockets, watchkit, nsstream

I have an old Watch OS app that I need to update for WatchOS 6. Right now the watch app uses the iPhone extension to communicate with a computer that's running a server using NSStream. This is very slow. I can send messages, which are received by the computer with a noticeable delay. Now that Watch apps can be standalone, is there any way the watch can communicate directly with a computer without an iPhone and have it be much faster? It would need to be able to stream the data fairly quickly like you can do with NSStream. Is this possible, or will I still need to rely on an iOS companion app? Thanks

Comment: What WatchOS version was your app written for?

Comment: Currently written for the original WatchKit, but am willing to rewrite the whole thing. I haven't been able to make it a standalone app since it relies on the iPhone app for network communication.